# Playing a Sound in Cocoa every time you Touch the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to play a sound every time I tap the screen in my game...

Basically, every time my character jumps, I wan't a little sound to play. Unfortunately it appears to only play the loop if the loop (from the previous jump) has already finished playing from the previous session... Meaning I don't actually get the sound affect every time I touch the screen...

Using this framework:

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

This is how I load my file:

```
 -(void)LoadMusic{
     NSString *jumpSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Burst" ofType:@"mp3"];
     jumpAffect = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:jumpSound] error:NULL];
     jumpAffect.delegate = self;
 }
```

Calling it in viewDidLoad:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
     [self LoadMusic];
     ...
     [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

And this is when I want it to play (every time I touch the screen (making the character jump):

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
     [jumpAffect play];
     jump = 16;
 }
```

Is there something I'm forgetting to enable loops to be played over each other? or can I stop the loop and restart it if it is still playing when the next touch occurs?

Comment: You'll need more than one `AVAudioPlayer` if you want to play more than one sound at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self playJumpSound];
}

- (void)playJumpSound {
  AVAudioPlayer *jumpEffect = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:jumpSound] error:NULL];
  [jumpEffect play];
}
```

If you find that loading your sound is too slow, load a handful of them up-front, then reuse the players.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for posting. This has solved my problem... It now reloads and replays the sound affect every time I touch it... :)

Comment: You should probably run a memory leak analysis on this source just in case. I didn't, so it could be leaking (especially if you're not using ARC).

Comment: What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use Instruments in XCode and choose the Leaks instrument, then tap your screen a bunch, pop the view controller that spawned them off the stack, and see if any leaks are recorded.